# CodeIgniter and Minify Index.php clash

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, minify

I am using CodeIgniter which has an htaccess file in the root directory:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Minify library folder is also placed in the root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# You may need RewriteBase on some servers
#RewriteBase /min

# rewrite URLs like "/min/f=..." to "/min/?f=..."
RewriteRule ^([bfg]=.*)  index.php?$1 [L,NE]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
# In case AddOutputFilterByType has been added
SetEnv no-gzip
</IfModule>
```

The problem is, when I navigate so my site on localhost, I get sent to the `index.php` file in minify which is asking me for Minify Builder Credentials.
How does I fix this so the homepage doesn't go to the Minify folder?

Comment: Is the second block of text also present in your .htaccess file?  If not, what file is it from?

Comment: @dg99 there 2 htaccess files. One directly in the document root, the other inside the min folder, which is also inside the document root so: `/htaccessForCodeIgniter and /min/htaccessForMinify`

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting `#RewriteBase /min` ?

Comment: @IkoTikashi ha! that worked how dumb was I. Create an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncomment `#RewriteBase /min` to set a rewrite base path for the minify rules.